# NSManagedObject and MKAnnotation

Tags: mkmapview, swift3

I am trying to extend a NSManagedObject called Location.

First I do this and it give me an error:

[image]

I want to set this property through a method on the nsmanagedobject. 
How do I add such a property?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it an optional by adding  a "?"

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by finding this hint  @objc :

```
    @objc
private override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitude, self.longitude)
    self.overlayCircle = MKCircle(center:  self.coordinate, radius: self.radius as CLLocationDistance)

}
```